# Blazor OnSubmit does not update Models Values

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a simple `EditForm`, however whenever I hit submit the model is not updating and thus not posting the correct infromation.

```
<EditForm Model="model" OnSubmit="@Submit" FormName="PostCardsTotals">
    <label>Count</label>
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="model.CountOfCards" class="form-control" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</EditForm>
```

My code looks like this:

```
@code {
    [Parameter] 
    public int? Id { get; set; }

[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private Metrics model { get; set; } = new Metrics ();

private List<Metrics>? m = new List<Metrics> 

 [Inject]
 public IMetricServcie? metricService { get; set; }

 protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
 {
     if(Id != null) model = await collabriaSerivce.GetCollabriaCardMetricAsync(Id.Value, Selection);
 }

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     m = await metricsService.GetMetricsToList();
 }

 async Task Submit()
 {
     // handle the submit
     if (Id != null)
     {
         var res = await service.UpdateMetrics(Id.Value, Selection, model);
     }

 }

}
```

When I hit submit I can see in my browser tools that the `model.CountOfCours` has the proper value, however it's not updating server side.

Am I missing something?

Comment: That means the problem is in `service.UpdateMetrics`, not `OnSubmit`. The values are stored when the input elements raise a change anyway, before `Submit` is even clicked

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, however when I use a breakpoint on that method I can see that model still has the old values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnParametersSetAsync()` and  `OnInitializedAsync()` would be calded  before `Submit()`,the value you posted would be overrided  by the data you read from db

Try add a check before you load the data:

```
[SupplyParameterFromForm]
public Metrics? model { get; set; } 

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (model is null)
    {
        model = //load data from db
    }
    
}
```